# Oracle Apex Authentication scheme?

Tags: authentication, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

Ok, I want to achieve authentication in my APEX applications by redirecting to a Custom Enterprise Authentication URL ex. https://example.com/login.asp.

This page has ASP Server Header Variables, so for example when the variable HTTP_SCUSER contains my authenticated username gaudyk4d, the it should redirect back to my APEX homepage

How can I do this?

I am also open to suggestions, I am thinking

- How can I get the values in the Server variables without doing the above? My APEX URL looks like https://apex.web.page/ords/f?p=..... (ORDS) hosted on weblogic
- Custom authentication scheme HTTP header variables?